# Magic Mouse Disconnects

Tags: bluetooth

I have a magic mouse on my Ubuntu 14.04.2 system. It works pretty well, except it disconnects for no reason, and reconnects a minute later. Unsure why this is occurring. I changed the batteries in the device, and it works fine on my mac.

I had a similar(ish) issue with my wifi and had to disable a power saving feature. Could there be something similar with the bluetooth adapter?

Comment: Does it happen when connected to wifi?  If so add the results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to your question as it might be a problem with bluetooth coexistance

Comment: I have the problem as well, though I am always on wifi so I can't tell if it would be fine otherwise without being unproductive for a few hours.  My network controller is an Intel 82579LM and Advanced-N 6205 AGN, also on 14.04

Comment: I have the same problem, with a Ubuntu Mate, Have you found any solution?

Comment: Never figured it out, sorry Albert.